# computer stop responding after ryzen master wrong configuration

Tags: amd-ryzen

I played with ryzen master config yesterday, and set memory clock to 3000(1600 by default) Application told me, that I should reboot computer to apply changes. After reboot computer can't see any USB ports, can't show anything on monitor.
I have the following hardware:

- AMD Ryzen 2600,  Asus TUF B450M pro-gaming,  Rx580,  Aegis ddr4 3200

So, I tried to short headers to drop boot config, but this not working for me. I tried to set another ddr4 plane, same result. All fans working normally, rgb lighting and so on. Help me, please, don't wanna go service.

Comment: Would that be a B450 iso a BM450?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille oh, sorry, B450M

Comment: Just came across "While there are some nearly fool-proof, automated methods for overclocking your AMD Ryzen CPU, it’s important to note that pushing anything beyond its normal operating point has inherent risks that range from system instability to the unfortunate early failure of components. And, if you break your CPU by overclocking, it will not be covered by warranty." on tomshardware, where they have a forum for overclockers.  But could you break a CPU by overclocking memory?

Comment: "I tried to short headers", what about removing the CMOS battery for a while?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I think that problem is not about cpu, of course, i checked the warranty warning. I think this can be connected with bios configuration, which now is wrong. From other sources i found interesting information, that ryzen master write configuration separately from bios, which causes problems when you try to change parameters in bios.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille tried to to do it in according to user manual, short contacts with removed bios battery

Comment: Removing the rx580, connecting monitor to MB?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille same result

Comment: So you can't even enter the bios?

Comment: Did you reset bios/RTC ? https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1040820

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 yes, no result, i cant enter bios

Comment: Too bad you stepped too far at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After service, I can say, that it was bios corruption.
So if u faced with this problem, without furter interuption go to service and flash bios.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.